# I cannot find .htaccess in wordpress files deployed in appservice azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, .htaccess

I need to add below values in .htaccess but the file does not exist in root folder.

```
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value max_file_uploads 128M
php_value max_input_vars 5000
```

Please help

Comment: First thing I would try is to create a htaccess file and put it in the rooter folder. Already tried?

Comment: @rank I have no idea how to make one.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/  this can help. just make it in a code editor like visual studio code and call the file `.htaccess` so it has no name and just the file type